# Problema con move_uploaded_file

Tags: php

Estoy intentando subir imágenes a la BD mediante un formulario , he podido subirlo perfectamente el problema es que la imagen que selecciono no se mueve a la carpeta donde tengo el resto de imágenes,
lo raro es que no me da ningún error:

```
<div class="input-group">
        
        <label>Imagen:</label>
       <input type="file" id="imagen" name="imagen" accept="image/*">
        
        
        
        </div>
$imagen = $_FILES['imagen']["tmp_name"];
            $nombre = $_FILES['imagen']["name"];
            $tipo = $_FILES['imagen']["type"];
            $tamano = $_FILES['imagen']["size"];
            $destino = SITEURL/"img/".$nombre;
            echo $imagen;
            
            $subido = move_uploaded_file($imagen, $destino);
//comprobar si funciona
            if($prueba==true){
```

Comment: Creo que el problema está en la variable destino, la cual no puede ser el nombre de dominio /img sino que deberias de poner la ruta de los archivos, por ejemplo "/var/www/nombredominio/img" algo asi.

Comment: Por lo que veo, tenes un error de concatenación, puntualmente acá `$destino = SITEURL/"img/".$nombre;`. No estoy seguro, pero mi inclino a pensar que debería ser algo así: `$destino = SITEURL . "/img/" . $nombre;`

Comment: Si , aparte de ese error , la dirección estaba mal , al final he puesto la dirección de xamp y ha funcionado .